# How to extract the nodes from a tree view dialogue from an .MSI file

Tags: .net, wix, treeview, windows-installer

**Short version -** I have an MSI file with a TreeView object for specifiying modules to include in the installation. These can be passed using command line arguments but unfortunately the authors didn't release a list of components for automating the installation. Is there any way of extracting the **TreeView object *and the friendly names or descriptions associated*** from the MSI file?

I have tried using Orca to extract the Components table, which contains the component names of the from the .MSI but it doesn't contain friendly names or descriptions visible in the TreeView section of the User Interface.

**Background (you can skip this)**

I have an set of installation packages with their own MSI files. Each is called in turn by a single Setup.exe created by a team I can't communicate with. To automate the installation I can pass the components I want to install for the relevant MSI file by calling

`Setup.exe [/productinstallerargs=args]`

However, the list of components published by the authors hasn't been updated in 2 years while there has been a number of new builds and added components. To automate newer versions using a silent install, including the needed components, I require a list of component names as passed to the Setup.exe along with their frienldy names; the friendly names are the ones which the people deploying the software can understand.

The most obvious way to me to do this is to get the TreeView object from the MSI which link to the component names and friendly names in one place. Once I have both of these names per component I can take a list of the friendly names of components that engineers need to install and produce the correct arguments needed for a silent install with all the packages they need. So any help getting the friendly names which match the component names by extracting the TreeView object from the MSI or any other method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try using dark.exe to decompile the MSI into wxs files. It might preserve all the feature enabling conditions and stuff, do all the feature->component mappings for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have your terminology wrong. The list of optional parts to install is in the Feature table in most standard installs. Components are mostly single files bundled into features.

The Feature table has the treeview - see Feature and Feature_Parent columns - and Title and Description are the friendly name and the description of the feature.

Comment: Spot on. When I saw every additional module in the Component table I assumed that was the one I wanted.